# SQL query convert into linq

Tags: sql-server, linq, c#-4.0

How to convert this SQL statement to linq?

```
SELECT 
    ICRE.CampaignID,
    MAX(ICRE.CampaignsRegularEvaluaterID) AS CampaignsRegularEvaluaterID,
    MAX(ICC.Name) AS CampaingName
FROM
    INN_Customers_Campaigns_EvaluationStage ICCES
INNER JOIN 
    INN_Campaigns_RegularEvaluaters ICRE ON ICRE.CampaignsEvaluationStageID = ICCES.Id
INNER JOIN 
    INN_Customers_Campaingns ICC ON ICC.Id = ICCES.CampaignId
INNER JOIN 
    INN_Customers_Teams t ON t.Id = ICRE.RegularEvaluaterID
LEFT JOIN 
    INN_Customers_Campaigns_EvaluationStage ICCES1 ON ICCES1.CampaignId = ICCES.CampaignId
WHERE 
    ICRE.RegularEvaluaterID = @userid
    AND ICCES1.Sequence IS NOT NULL
    AND ICRE.IsEvaluated IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    ICRE.CampaignID;
```

Comment: On an unrelated note to the question, you should try to keep your object names consistant. You have `Customers_Campaingns` and `Customers_Campaigns`. I, assume, the former is a typographical error but if you aren't far down the developement I would suggest fixing it to avoid confusion.

Comment: *Don't* convert it to LINQ. LINQ isn't SQL or a replacement for SQL. It's a language that works on top of an ORM. It's the *ORM's* job to map entities to tables, configure relations and generate joins from those relations.

Comment: On the other hand, an ORM is meant to map *entities* to relational storage, not execute reports, and this is a reporting query. It's far better to create a view of functions for this query and map an entity to it, eg in EF. It's a lot easier to optimize the query if a view is used. You could create an index on top of the view for example, or replace the multi-table join with a flat reporting table, similar to how star schemas work

Comment: And what have you tried so far?